# Mocking class return NULL even after set the value manually

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, powermockrunner

I'm new to unit testing and try to understand how mocking works. I got the code as below, where I mock `PdRequest.class` using `PowerMockRunner`. However, it return `Null` for all the variables. I also tried to set the value manually but its the same. Is there anything that I missing? and Is it better if I just create `new PdRequest()` and set all the values manually?

**What I tried**
-Try to use `@PrepareForTest` and `@ExtendWith`
-Try to put `initMocks(this)`

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class PerformanceServiceImplTest
```

```
 PdRequest pdRequest = mock(PdRequest.class);
        when(pdRequest.getLoginUserId()).thenReturn("42");
        when(pdRequest.getYear()).thenReturn("Year");
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setLoginUserId((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setCurrMetric((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setCurrentLink((BreadCrumLink) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setFullView((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setManagerId((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setMetric((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setPdBoard((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setRegionId((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setRoleId((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setRoleLevel((Integer) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setRoleName((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setSalesAbf((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setSalesMm((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setSalesRsme((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setStaffId((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setStaffIdList((List<String>) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setTeamId((String) any());
        doNothing().when(pdRequest).setYear((String) any());
        pdRequest.setCurrMetric("Curr Metric");
        pdRequest.setCurrentLink(breadCrumLink);
        pdRequest.setFullView("Full View");
        pdRequest.setLoginUserId("42");
        pdRequest.setManagerId("42");
        pdRequest.setMetric("Metric");
        pdRequest.setPdBoard("Pd Board");
        pdRequest.setRegionId("us-east-2");
        pdRequest.setRoleId("42");
        pdRequest.setRoleLevel(1);
        pdRequest.setRoleName("Role Name");
        pdRequest.setSalesAbf("Sales Abf");
        pdRequest.setSalesMm("Sales Mm");
        pdRequest.setSalesRsme("Sales Rsme");
        pdRequest.setStaffId("42");
        pdRequest.setStaffIdList(new ArrayList<>());
        pdRequest.setTeamId("42");
        pdRequest.setYear("Year");
```

**Output**
[image: Debugging object]

Comment: My recommendation: if you are new to testing, avoid Mockito. Write tests with plain Java. After you've become comfortable with writing basic tests, you can start learning Mockito. It is absolutely possible to write tests without Mockito (and often leads to better-designed classes)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore what IntelliJ is showing you. That shows you the *state*, which is inherited from the class you're mocking. However, you haven't set that state in the mock, and that state is not returned when any method is called. Instead, you've configured the Mockito internal fields (`CGLIB$BOUND` etc.) to return those values.

Comment: is the state you mentioned is ```when().thenReturn()```?

Comment: The state of any object is the collection of all its fields and their values. Because you set values on a mock, the actual fields are not set - the setters are intercepted by the mock's internal mechanisms. If you want an object that has its fields set, use `spy(new PdRequest())` instead of `mock(PdRequest.class)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of getting the value. From https://www.toptal.com/java/a-guide-to-everyday-mockito .

```
        PdRequest pdRequest = mock(PdRequest.class);
        doAnswer(InvocationOnMock::callRealMethod).when(pdRequest).setLoginUserId("42");
        doAnswer(InvocationOnMock::callRealMethod).when(pdRequest).getLoginUserId();
        pdRequest.setLoginUserId("42");
        assertEquals("42", pdRequest.getLoginUserId());
```

Comment: One question: you tell your mock to call the real method for every method. Why not use the real thing in the first place? A lot simpler than going through a mock. Can't you simply do `PdRequest pdRequest = new PdRequest()` and be done?

Comment: yes, that is much easier to do. But as I said in the question, I try to understand how the mocking works and how to write it. that's why I insist to use ```mock()```.

Comment: But you are not really mocking nor stubbing. You have a "mock" that does "nothing" for a lot of methods and delegates to the real class for 2 methods.

Comment: The code in the question was written using ```diffblue cover``` extension from IntelliJ. Sorry for the confusion there.